# Why is the argmax of this random variable the same as the other two?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I believe this is the answer but I have trouble convincing myself that this is true and need help proving so.

X and Y are random variables with the same variance. Let Z be a random variable that is X with probability 1/2 and Y with probability 1/2. Also let

The unique $argmax_q E[S(q,X)] = Var(X)$

The unique $argmax_q E[S(q,Y)] = Var(Y)$

Then I think that $argmax_q E[S(q,Z)] = Var(X) = Var(Y)$, but am lacking a formal explanation of why.

I wanted to say that $argmax_q E[S(q,Z)] = argmax_q (1/2E[S(q,X)] + 1/2E[S(q,Y)])$ but am not sure what formal reasoning results in this conclusion.

Comment: What is $S(q,\cdot)$?

Comment: In the context of this problem $S(q,.)$ is a scoring rule that took a prediction $q$ and a result that is drawn from a distribution. The output is a payoff dependent on how good the prediction was compared to the actual result. The function itself is arbitrary

Comment: FYI: for $\arg\!\max$, write ``\arg\!\max``. And say ``\operatorname{Var}`` for $\operatorname{Var}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $Z=BX+(1-B)Y$ with $B\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $X,Y,B$ mutually independent.

Fix any $q$.
$$
\mathbb{E}[S(q,Z)] =
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[S(q,BX+(1-B)Y)|B]]
$$
Now, for any fixed $b\in\{0,1\}$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[S(q,BX+(1-B)Y)|B] = \begin{cases}
S(q,X) &\text{ if } b=1\\
S(q,Y) &\text{ if } b=0
\end{cases}
= BS(q,X)+(1-B)S(q,Y)
$$
and so
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[S(q,Z)] &=
\mathbb{E}[B \mathbb{E}[S(q,X)]+(1-B)\mathbb{E}[S(q,Y)]]
= \mathbb{E}[B]\mathbb{E}[S(q,X)]+\mathbb{E}[(1-B)]\mathbb{E}[S(q,Y)]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[S(q,X)] + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[S(q,Y)]
\end{align}$$
where we used independence of $X,B$ and that of $Y,B$.

So, that's a long-winded way of proving the inequality you saw was intuitively true.:
$$
\forall q, \qquad \mathbb{E}[S(q,Z)] =\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[S(q,X)] + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[S(q,Y)] \tag{1}
$$